# Can we link two Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, links

I want to make a link between two spreadsheets, like if I click on a code in a cell, it opens the spreadsheet which the code refers/links to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [enter a link in a Google spreadsheet](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44660&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=-1uxgby3u4d8o4&cbrank=3).

The syntax of the command is: `=hyperlink("url";"Phrase")`

The key is that the Google spreadsheet you want to open has a URL.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Google Sheet Add-on called Sheetgo. It's easy to use and after installing, gives you the ability to link sheet in many way, even if you need to connect multiple sheets.

Comment: Can you link to the add on?