# How to link two spreadsheet of Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we do a link between two Google Docs spreadsheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27749/can-we-do-a-link-between-two-google-docs-spreadsheets)

I'm trying to link two Google spreadsheets. I don't want to merge

I would like to have a spreadsheet with the data of my clients and link with the. I can't have the data in the same spreadsheet because I've shared with people and they can't see all the data of my clients

Then I'll have my sales in one document and in other I can have the resume of the data

Comment: It sounds a little different than your link. I think what he meant was cross sheet referencing.

Answer (score 5):

Don't click on it, just pay attention to the URL format.

> Examine an example spreadsheet URL https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AqhqY231XZd3cFBiY2VqeWdmNWdhaDBqTnNxVi1sVlE&hl=en
>
> In this URL the bolded section **0AqhqY231XZd3cFBiY2VqeWdmNWdhaDBqTnNxVi1sVlE** between key= and &hl= is the key.

We are going to use ImportRange to cross reference the spreadsheet.
Here is the sample format
=ImportRange( "KeyName" ; "SheetName!FirstCell:LastCell" )

**This isn't fool proof, but it will give you the ability to include data from hidden sources and protect the sensitive numbers from being seen by other clients.**

Comment: Without the link this answer is useless. Answers should be complete in and of themselves. At _best_ this should be a comment.

Comment: I have updated the answer, and written clear instructions now.